# Change 1 gang switch two lights to 2 gang switch for each

Tags: electrical, switch, light

Hi I have a single 1 gang switch that turns on two lights together, now I want to replace it with a single 2 gang switch to control both lights individually.

What I found behind the switch are 7 coloured wires. 1 red by itself, I know it is the live wire. Then three (red, green/yellow, black) from one light and another three from another light.

How they are currently connected is like this: the single red live wire into one slot, the two red wires from the two lights are twisted together into another slot. Then the two green/yellow wires are twisted together and the two black wires are twisted together.

In order to separate them, how do you connect them so that:

Option 1. each gang control each light

Option 2. light B can be controlled only when light A is on (i.e. if light A is off light B always off)

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box?

Comment: There must be another black or blue, and another green/yellow.

Comment: Sorry I dont have a photo. May be I can describe clearer? Which part needs clarification?
What do you mean another wires? There are only seven wires separated in three groups as far as I can see.